# Spark - Transforming key-value pairs into columns

Tags: apache-spark, pivot, transform

I'm having 100,000 files, each contains data for M items, and each item has N attributes, with the format of each file is like this:

```
itemID,key,value    
item1_1,key1,value1
item1_1,key2,value2
...
item1_1,keyN,valueN
item1_2,key1,value1
...
item1_2,keyN,valueN
...
item1_M,keyN,valueN
```

(1st file has data for items from item1_1 to item1_M. 2nd file has data for items from item2_1 to item2_M,...)

For further processing, I want to transform the data into a DataFrame like:

```
item1_2,v1,v2,...,vN
...
item1000000_M,v1,v2,...,vN
```

I tried to achieve this by using Spark's pivot:

```
val df = spark.read.csv("/path/*")
df.groupBy("itemID").pivot("key",Seq("key1","key2",...,"keyN")).agg(first("value"))
```

For 10GB of zipped data, it took hours to complete. I believe that using the pivot function is not a good idea here, but don't know of any alternative options yet.
What can be a better approach?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Is it 10GB of `gzip` data?

Comment: To extend on @philantrovert comment - huge gzip file is probably a bigger problem issue than `pivot`. Uncompress data before using Spark and see if it help.

Comment: Yes, 10GB of gzip data in total. However, that consists 100,000 small gzip files, with each has size of ~100KB.
As Spark can read gzip files directly, and my files are on AWS S3, so I don't want to decompress it first.
I also tried to unzip and tested with files on my PC, but didn't see much improvement.

Comment: I am also new in this technology .may be it works , Make rwo rdds and and combine it may be it takes less time

Comment: @swapnilkambe: Could you please help elaborate your idea?

Comment: could you please provide the schema of two files

Comment: @swapnilkambe: I think there's some misunderstanding here: I have 100,000 .csv files of the same structure that I mentioned in my original post, not only 2 files. Sorry for being confusing.